# How to conditionally remove subarrays based on specific element's value?

Tags: php, arrays, null, filtering

I have an array of 13 elements

```
$vcpes= 
array:13 [▼
  0 => array:23 [▼
    "cpe_mac" => "665544332211"
    "bandwidth_max_up" => 300000
    "bandwidth_max_down" => 500000
    "filter_icmp_inbound" => null
    "dmz_enabled" => null
    "dmz_host" => null
    "vlan_id" => null
    "dns" => []
    "xdns_mode" => null
    "cfprofileid" => null
    "stub_response" => null
    "acl_mode" => null
    "portal_url" => null
    "fullbandwidth_max_up" => null
    "fullbandwidth_max_down" => null
    "fullbandwidth_guaranty_up" => null
    "fullbandwidth_guaranty_down" => null
    "account_id" => 1000 // <--- Keep 
    "location_id" => null
    "network_count" => null
    "group_name" => null
    "vse_id" => null
    "firewall_enabled" => null
  ]
  1 => array:23 [▼
    "cpe_mac" => "213243546576"
    "bandwidth_max_up" => null
    "bandwidth_max_down" => null
    "filter_icmp_inbound" => null
    "dmz_enabled" => null
    "dmz_host" => null
    "vlan_id" => null
    "dns" => []
    "xdns_mode" => null
    "cfprofileid" => null
    "stub_response" => null
    "acl_mode" => null
    "portal_url" => null
    "fullbandwidth_max_up" => null
    "fullbandwidth_max_down" => null
    "fullbandwidth_guaranty_up" => null
    "fullbandwidth_guaranty_down" => null
    "account_id" => null  // <--- Delete
    "location_id" => null
    "network_count" => null
    "group_name" => null
    "vse_id" => null
    "firewall_enabled" => null
  ]
  2 => array:23 [▶]
  3 => array:23 [▶]
  4 => array:23 [▶]
  5 => array:23 [▶]
  6 => array:23 [▶]
  7 => array:23 [▶]
  8 => array:23 [▶]
  9 => array:23 [▶]
  10 => array:23 [▶]
  11 => array:23 [▶]
  12 => array:23 [▶]
]
```

I want to delete the ones that have `account_id == null`.

I tried to decode it:

`$vcpes = json_decode (json_encode ( $vcpes), FALSE);`

and to check it:

```
foreach($vcpes as $vcpe){
    if($vcpe->account_id == null){
        //delete it
    }else{
        //don't delete it
    }
}
```

I hope some one can give me a little hint on this.

Comment: `if($vcpe['account_id'] == null)`

Comment: `$result = array_filter($originalArray, function($value) { return $value['account_id'] !== null; });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->` is for getting object's property. To get a value from an array use `$array['key']` notation.

```
foreach($vcpes as $i => $vcpe){
    if ($vcpe['account_id'] === null) {
        unset($vcpes[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I decode it therefore I use the arrow. Sorry for update my post too slow. But you're answering my question. :)

Comment: I like the `unset()` suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way, or just use `array_filter()` as commented by @Mark Baker

```
$finalArray = [];
foreach($vcpes as $vcpe){
    if($vcpe->account_id != null){
        $finalArray[] = $vcpe;
    }
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($finalArray);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: Good Suggestion, I will add this to my PHP toolbox. Thanks Sunny.